# VS Code GDB debugging doesn't work in integrated terminal, but it works in external terminal

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

I'm on windows 10 and have set up C debugging in VS code using MinGW. In the launch.json file, if I set `"externalConsole": true"` then everything works as expected, and I can debug properly. However if it is set to `"externalConsole": false"`, then the integrated VS code terminal tries to run:

```
"cmd /C "c:\Users\16479\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.1.3\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-iphorouu.0fb --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-10cbyjg3.wkd --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-pj3ilqfq.afl --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-k5ph25ah.bz2 --dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi "
```

and it outputs

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Which makes sense because I've never heard of `cmd` being a thing in a terminal. But it is something you can run in the Windows Run tool to open a command prompt. So it seems like VS code is trying to run the same command it used to open the external terminal, but it isn't working in the integrated terminal.

This is just my theory I'm not an expert, but if anyone knows anything about this or has a solution to let me debug in the integrated terminal it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I set the default shell to Powershell instead of Command Prompt in VS code.